# Is there an equivalent to chdropboxsync for iCloud?

Tags: icloud

My app needs to keep one single directory of RTF files synchronized with either Dropbox or iCloud. For Dropbox, chdropboxsync does all the heavy lifting. Is there an equivalent for iCloud? I must admit I'm a little spooked by all the stories I hear of iCloud becoming a major issue in terms of user experience and app quality, so using a peer-tested framework would take a big load off my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no" - for now. I have constructed a nice little framework that integrates chdropboxsync in a text editor abstraction, and am working on adding iCloud to it. Perhaps soon...

Comment: Hi Anders, have you succeeded in making a working iCloud framework?

Comment: Sorry no. Dropbox was so easy to do and seems to work for all my users, and so I focused on other tasks.

Comment: Thanks Anders. Is your framework public domain? I'd love to have another option.

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have the time to package and support it really. I am super busy - as it is, my app development is a hobby that is crowded by a full time job and family w. two kids (and three cats).

Comment: no worries, thanks for responding. Meantime, have a look at eitap.com and their iCloudAgentSDK